# Creating an instance for a typeclass throws :"Couldn't match expected type ‘f’ with actual type"

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and i'm trying to learn how to use classe,

I have the class:

```
class SomeClass f where
doSome :: Integer -> f
```

the data type:

```
 data SomeData = D1 Integer 
                | D2 SomeData SomeData
```

and I'm trying to create the instance:

```
instance SomeClass SomeData where
doSome x = D1 x
```

but the ghci gives me the error:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘f’ with actual type ‘SomeClass’

I've seen some question regarding this issue, but i couldn't make them work for me.

how can i fix this?

Comment: The indentation is wrong, and I really doubt your method is named `do`. Can you provide your actual code?

Comment: @ Red Barton Tnx! - you're  right, my indentation was wrong (the names also, I edited my question to reflect that but that's not the important part). after fixing it, it compiled and run as expected (arrr the errors code wasn't  useful at all)

Comment: @ Red Barton this will teach me to indent after a 'where' clause

Comment: OK, great. I must admit it never occurred to me that it's syntactically valid to put an instance declaration between a function's type signature and its definition.

Comment: Don't update the question with the fix... now it looks like you asked "I have [perfectly working code here], why doesn't it work?"

Comment: @immibis apparently you didn't read the comment explaining that the problem i had was with indentation - a problem that still exists in the code example in the question (the current code in the example wouldn't compile!!!). you shouldn't be so quick to criticise before even understanding the issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `D1` after `D2` is not valid here:

```
data SomeData = D1 Integer 
                | D2 D1 D1
                     ^^^^^
```

Where `D1` occurs after `D2` you need a type, but `D1` is a function.

You probably meant to write:

```
data SomeData = D1 Integer 
                | D2 SomeData SomeData
```

With this change your code compiles. (I also change the name `do` to another name which is not a Haskell keyword):

```
data SomeData = D1 Integer | D2 SomeData SomeData

class SomeClass f where
  foo :: Integer -> f

instance SomeClass SomeData where
  foo x = D1 x
```

Comment: the problem was with the indentation (my code was identical to yours except for the indentation...), tnx for the help!!